# How can I access a hidden member from a derived class?

Tags: delphi, variables, scope, superclass

I have two classes, one derived from the other. These classes both introduce variables with the same name. The variable in the derived class hides that in the super class.

How can I refer to the super class's variable from a method of the derived class?

```
type
  TClass1 = class
  protected
    FMyVar: Integer;
  end;

  TClass2 = class(TClass1)
  protected
    FMyVar: Integer;
  public
    procedure Foo;
  end;

procedure TClass2.Foo;
begin
  //here I want access to FMyVar from TClass1
end;
```

Comment: Since you didn't specified any directive for visibility of your class members, the members become `published`, so they're accesible in the most public way from a class descendant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing special. Each subclass automatically has access to things from its parent class, except those members that were marked `private` in the parent.

Sublasses declared in the same unit as their parent have access to members marked `private`. Use `strict private` instead to *really* prevent subclasses from accessing their inherited members.

Comment: Yes. Thank You. I'm sorry: I forgot to describe the main problem. In superclass and in its derived are variables with the same name. How to choose the one from superclass?

Answer (score 5):

You can gain access with a cast:

```
procedure TClass2.Foo;
begin
  DoSomething(TClass1(Self).FMyVar);
end;
```

As a side note, I suggest you reconsider your design. The path you are taking leads to confusion and bugs.

Comment: @Artik If this is perfect (and to me this is the answer to your question) why did you accept Rob's answer which - as to your comment - did not answer?

Comment: @Sir Rufo Rob answered the question that was originally asked. Then we edited it to ask this question. Which I answered. It's a bit odd. Rob's answer doesn't fit with the original question. But the original question is a bit of a non question. This question is much more interesting.